# What is the difference between Neo4j with PowerShell and Neo4j as a service?

Tags: powershell, neo4j, windows-services, invoke-command

In [this comment](https://community.neo4j.com/t/neo4j-desktop-is-running-but-neo4j-status-still-says-that-the-server-is-not-running/45443/4?u=ooker) a staff of Neo4j says:

> I would not recommend mixing each of these methods for running the database, as they're not suited for working together. You should pick one of:
>
> - Neo4j Desktop
> - Neo4j with PowerShell
> - Neo4j as a windows service
> - Neo4j with Docker
> - Neo4j Aura

What is the difference between Neo4j with PowerShell and Neo4j as a service? Checking the [Windows installation - Operations Manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/windows/) I take that by Neo4j with PowerShell he means [Neo4j PowerShell module](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/windows/#powershell). But in my understanding it also requires you to install Neo4j service with the command `Invoke-Neo4j install-service` before you can `Invoke-Neo4j start`. I take that in PowerShell `Invoke-Neo4j` is equivalent to the standalone `neo4j` command, given that you have imported the module via `Import-Module .\Neo4j-Management.psd1`?

Comment: Pretty sure "Neo4j with PowerShell" refers to the approach he describes in that same answer - running Neo4j in the console without installing as a service by executing `Invoke-Neo4j console`.

Comment: In PowerShell, is `Invoke-Neo4j` equivalent to `neo4j`? Because in both case I still need to install a service to start the server

Comment: No, `Invoke-Neo4j` is a PowerShell cmdlet you can use to either install (as a service) or start (without installing a service) a new instance of `neo4j`. I imagine it ultimately calls the `neo4j` executable

Comment: but I still have to `Invoke-Neo4j install-service` before I can `Invoke-Neo4j start`, so I guess one cannot start a new instance of `neo4j` without installing a service? Also, I though `neo4j` is a [service](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/windows/#windows-service "Windows installation - Operations Manual") itself?

Comment: Did you try `Invoke-Neo4 console`?

Comment: hmm, I think I'm starting getting it. Do you mean that besides `Invoke-Neo4j console` which can start a DBSM server, the rest of the commands from the module (e.g. `Invoke-Neo4j start`, `Invoke-Neo4j status`, `Invoke-Neo4j install-service`, etc) are to work with the service and are the same with the commands from neo4j.bat (e.g. `neo4j start`, `neo4j status`, `neo4j install-service`, etc)? Why don't they just provide one thing?

Comment: Presumably because they want to afford users the option to choose whatever deployment type fits their need? You really should be asking on https://community.neo4j.com/, not here :)

Comment: I see. Nevertheless, I guess you have given the answer. If you make it as an answer, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the conversation with @Mathias R. Jessen, I think that besides `Invoke-Neo4j console` which can start a DBSM server, the rest of the commands from the module (e.g. `Invoke-Neo4j start`, `Invoke-Neo4j status`, `Invoke-Neo4j install-service`, etc) are to work with the service and are the same with the commands from neo4j.bat (e.g. `neo4j start`, `neo4j status`, `neo4j install-service`, etc). I think this mix of commands is to make it convenient to work with one thing.